# I'm trying to parallelize rat maze problem using openmp but it is taking too much time can anyone help me?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, breadth-first-search

The above parallelize code is taking much more time as compare to the original one. I have used bfs approach to solve the problem. I am getting the correct output but it is taking too much time.

(x, y) represents matrix cell coordinates, and
`dist` represents their minimum distance from the source

```
struct Node
{
    int x, y, dist;
};

 \\Below arrays detail all four possible movements from a cell
int row[] = { -1, 0, 0, 1 };
int col[] = { 0, -1, 1, 0 };
```

Function to check if it is possible to go to position (row, col)
from the current position. The function returns false if (row, col)
is not a valid position or has a value 0 or already visited.

```
bool isValid(vector<vector<int>> const &mat, vector<vector<bool>> &visited, int row, int col) 
{
    return (row >= 0 && row < mat.size()) && (col >= 0 && col < mat[0].size())
        && mat[row][col] && !visited[row][col];
}
```

Find the shortest possible route in a matrix `mat` from source
cell (i, j) to destination cell (x, y)

```
int findShortestPathLength(vector<vector<int>> const &mat, pair<int, int> &src,
                    pair<int, int> &dest)
{
    if (mat.size() == 0 || mat[src.first][src.second] == 0 ||
            mat[dest.first][dest.second] == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
 
    // `M × N` matrix
    int M = mat.size();
    int N = mat[0].size();
 
    // construct a `M × N` matrix to keep track of visited cells
    vector<vector<bool>> visited;
    visited.resize(M, vector<bool>(N));
 
    // create an empty queue
    queue<Node> q;
    
    // get source cell (i, j)
    int i = src.first;
    int j = src.second;
 
    // mark the source cell as visited and enqueue the source node
    visited[i][j] = true;
    q.push({i, j, 0});
 
    // stores length of the longest path from source to destination
    int min_dist = INT_MAX;
    // loop till queue is empty
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        // dequeue front node and process it
        Node node = q.front();
        q.pop();
 
        // (i, j) represents a current cell, and `dist` stores its
        // minimum distance from the source
        int i = node.x, j = node.y, dist = node.dist;

        // if the destination is found, update `min_dist` and stop
        if (i == dest.first && j == dest.second)
        {
            min_dist = dist;
            break;
        }
 
        // check for all four possible movements from the current cell
        // and enqueue each valid movement
       #pragma omp parallel for 
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            // check if it is possible to go to position
            // (i + row[k], j + col[k]) from current position
           #pragma omp task shared(i,visited,j)
            {
            if (isValid(mat, visited, i + row[k], j + col[k]))
            {
                // mark next cell as visited and enqueue it
                visited[i + row[k]][j + col[k]] = true;
                q.push({ i + row[k], j + col[k], dist + 1 });
            }
            }
        }
    }
 
    if (min_dist != INT_MAX) {
        return min_dist;
    }
 
    return -1;
}
```

main part of the code only contains a matrix and source and destination coordinates

```
int main()
{
  vector<vector<int>> mat =
    {
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
    };
    pair<int, int> src = make_pair(0, 0);
    pair<int, int> dest = make_pair(7, 5);
    int min_dist = findShortestPathLength(mat, src, dest);
    if (min_dist != -1)
    {
        cout << min_dist<<endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Destination cannot be reached from a given source"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have used shared variable but it is taking too much time.
**Can anyone help me?**

Comment: You pay to manage and synchronise 4 threads and access to 3 shared variables, but each thread only executes a single `if`-statement. Try to assign more (much more) work to each thread and try to make the threads independent from each other.

Comment: can you just guide me how to do that?

Comment: This is like gathering four people, having each one check if a single direction of movement is valid, and then they put an X in that spot on a maze map they must pass between them (because they only have one to share) and hand back to you, and then you gather four different people for each of those Xes that do the same, and then you repeat the process again until you're done.

Comment: @molbdnilo can you just give me the correct answer? I am very new to parallel programing

Comment: @UT_MISH29 This is a harder problem than it seems at first glance - see for instance [WIkipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_breadth-first_search) massive article.

Comment: The workload is very small in you example, the OpenMP has  overheads, so the parallel program will be slower than the serial one. Note also that you should not use `parallel for` and `tasks` simultaneously and your OpenMP code  have data race, which should be resolved. Another comment is that `vector<vector<type>>` is not not an efficient data structure for 2D arrays.

Comment: @Laci can you just help me in figuring out the optimised solution

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks buddy!! If you have any time than if you can please help me getting in the optimised solution

Comment: My suggestion is 1) first optimize the serial code: remove openmp directives and post a question about how to optimize the code. You can also consider to send the question to codereview.stackexchange.com.  I think an optimized code will be significantly faster 2) if the speedup is still not enough, you should ask a question about how to parallelize it.

Comment: @UT_MISH29 There's a lot to explain and to understand here. Probably too much for a single SO question, especially since the wikipedia article linked by molbdnilo is quite detailled and has code examples.  It seems like you just started with parallelization, so it might be better for you to learn about the topic step by step. Don't just rush to a working solution, but try to understand _why_ something works or doesn't work.

Comment: @churill Thanks for your time mate!!
Can you suggest some easy algorithim with which I can just start with parallelizing?

Comment: @Laci I think this whole approach is doomed. No code optimization is going to help here. See my answer for a better way.

Answer (score 1):

As people have remarked, you only get parallelism over the 4 directions; a better approach is to keep a set of sets of points: first the starting point, then all points you can reach from there in 1 step, then the ones you can reach in two steps.

With this approach you get more parallelism: you're building what's known as a "wave front" and all the points can be tackled simultaneously.

```
auto last_level = reachable.back();
vector<int> newly_reachable;
for ( auto n : last_level ) {
  const auto& row = graph.row(n);
  for ( auto j : row ) {
    if ( not reachable.has(j)
         and not any_of
         ( newly_reachable.begin(),newly_reachable.end(),
           [j] (int i) { return i==j; } ) )
      newly_reachable.push_back(j);
  }
}
if (newly_reachable.size()>0)
  reachable.push_back(newly_reachable);
```

(I have written this for a general DAG; writing your maze as a DAG is an exercise for the reader.)

However, this approach still has big problems: if two points on the current wave front decide to add the same new point, you have to resolve that.

For a very parallel approach you need to abandon the "push" model of adding new points altogether, and to go a "pull" model: in every "distance" iteration you loop over all points and ask, if I am not reachable, was one of my neighbors reachable? If so, mark me as reachable in one step more than that neighbor.

If you think about that last approach for a second (or two) you'll see that you are essentially doing a sequence of matrix-vector products, with the adjacency matrix and the currently reachable set. Except that you replace the scalar "+" operation by "min" and the scalar "*" by "+1". Read any tutorial about the interpretation of graph operations as linear algebra. Except that it's not really linear.