# C++ OpenMP Breadth First Search

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, openmp, breadth-first-search

I'm working on an implementation of breadth first search using C++.
My implementation looks something like;

BFS.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Includes.h"

class BFS {
    int _num_v;
    int _num_l;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> _adj_list;
    //std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>* _adj_list;
    //std::list<int>* adj_list;

public:

    std::vector<int> m_sbfs_results;
    std::vector<int> m_pbfs_results;
    std::vector<int> m_abfs_results;

    BFS(int v, int l)
    {
        this->_num_v = v;
        this->_num_l = l;
        this->_adj_list.resize(_num_l);
        this->m_sbfs_results.reserve(_num_v);
        this->m_pbfs_results.reserve(_num_v);
        this->m_abfs_results.reserve(_num_v);
        //_adj_list = new std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>[_num_v];
        //adj_list = new std::list<int>[num_v];
    }


    void add_edge(int v1, int v2/*, int w*/);
    void sbfs(int start);
    void pbfs(int start, int n_threads);
    void abfs(int start, int n_threads);

    void verify_bfs(std::vector<int> a, std::vector<int> b)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _num_v; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] != b[i])
            {
                std::cout << "a[" << i << "]=" << a[i] <<
                    " b[" << i << "]=" << b[i] << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
};
```

BFS.cpp

```cpp
#include "BFS.h"
#include <unordered_map>

void BFS::add_edge(int v, int w)
{
    //std::cout << "v: " << v << " w: " << w << std::endl;
    _adj_list.at(v).push_back(w);
    _adj_list.at(w).push_back(v);
}

void BFS::sbfs(int start)
{
    std::unordered_map<int, bool> visited(_num_l);
    for (int i = 0; i < _num_l; i++)
        visited[i] = false;

    std::queue<int> queue;
    visited[start] = true;
    queue.push(start);

    std::cout << "Sequential BFS starting from node " << start << "\n";

    //std::vector<int>::iterator i;

    while (!queue.empty())
    {
        start = queue.front();
        //std::cout << start << " ";
        m_sbfs_results.push_back(start);
        queue.pop();

        for (auto& node : _adj_list[start])
        {
            if (!visited[node])
            {
                visited[node] = true;
                queue.push(node);
            }
        }

        //for (i = _adj_list[start].begin();
        //  i != _adj_list[start].end();
        //  ++i)
        //{
        //  if (!visited[*i])
        //  {
        //      queue.push(*i);
        //      visited[*i] = true;
        //  }
        //}
    }
}

void BFS::pbfs(int start, int n_threads)
{
    omp_set_num_threads(n_threads);

    std::unordered_map<int, bool> visited(_num_l);
#pragma omp for nowait
    for (int i = 0; i < _num_l; i++)
        visited[i] = false;

    std::queue<int> local_queue; // T
    std::queue<int> queue; // S
    visited[start] = true;
    queue.push(start);

    std::cout << "Parallel BFS starting from node " << start << "\n";

    /*
    1. Each thread should store locally all the new verticies it discovers in T (queue)
    2. Place them all in common array S (queue)
    3. Go again!
    */


    while (!queue.empty())
    {
#pragma omp parallel firstprivate(local_queue)
        {
#pragma omp critical
            for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++)
            {
                if (!queue.empty())
                {
                    start = queue.front();
                    //std::cout << start << " ";
                    m_pbfs_results.push_back(start);
                    queue.pop();
                }
            }
#pragma omp barrier
#pragma omp for schedule(static) nowait
            for (int i = 0; i < _adj_list[start].size(); i++)
            {
                int node = _adj_list[start][i];
                if (!visited[node])
                {
                    visited[node] = true;
                    local_queue.push(node);
                }
            }
#pragma omp barrier
#pragma omp critical
                for (int i = 0; i < local_queue.size(); i++)
                {
                    queue.push(local_queue.front());
                    local_queue.pop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I try to run my parallelized BFS the amount of numbers that gets put into `m_pbfs_results` are different. One run I could have 421 items in the vector, 74, 302, ... The sequential one will always have the same result at 4194299 items.
When stepping through the code the numbers seems to all look fine. I can't really step through the entire list as there are so many vertices. I know that push_back isn't thread safe, but that shouldn't matter here as it is within a critical section.

tl;dr
Why doesn't `*_results.push_back(start);` within a critical section work as expected?

Comment: the `visited` is not properly synchronized afaict. (I'm not familiar with openmp)

Comment: I think this approach to BFS is not the right way to high efficiency. Please read my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71702340/im-trying-to-parallelize-rat-maze-problem-using-openmp-but-it-is-taking-too-muc

Comment: It not being efficient is fine. My question is about the push_back in the critical section.

Comment: 1) Your serial and parallel code are different, 2) you have data race during accessing `visited`. 3) `#pragma omp for nowait` has no effect because it is not in a parallel region (enable warning during compilation). 4) Using `#pragma omp for schedule(static) nowait` and a barrier is the same as if you do not use the `nowait` clause.

Comment: To point 1) I mean there is no `for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++)` loop in serial version.

Comment: Ah I think I understand what you mean. The parallel version are all sharing the same start and therefore overwriting each others `start`?

Comment: I modified my comment while you wrote your comment.

Comment: I think your intention was to use `#pragma omp single` instead of the first `#pragma omp critical`. My suggestion is to read a decent book about OpenMP.

Comment: I was thinking I could run through multiple items in the queue, so I ment to use critical. I think it would be easier tho to just go through one and one item from the queue and then thread the for loop. So in that case it would be omp single with no for loop.

Comment: `if (!visited[node]) { visited[node] = true; local_queue.push(node);  }` Is probably a problem as well? E.g., if two threads decides to check out the same node? Having this in a critical section would defeat the purpose of a local_queue, so I guess that's not a solution.